# AWS Glue crawlers - how to apply a custom classifier?

Tags: aws-glue

I have created a custom classifier but cannot find out how to apply it to any of my crawlers.  Thanks.

Comment: Please add more information. Question is too broad.

Comment: Are you a Glue user?  If so, tell me what information is missing.  If not, then it's not clear to me how you would know that something's missing.

Comment: The answer would likely be something along the lines of "visit the crawler definition page and the foo tab and note the little button in the far right bottom ..." or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

I have found it. The answer is: Edit Crawler, then flip the twisty to expand the "Description..." section, and it is at the bottom.

Comment: This is arguably the most silly UI I have ever seen in AWS console.